# Nested template using/typdef

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, using

Say I have this setup:

```cpp
template<typename T1>
struct A {
  template<typename T2>
  struct B {
    using type = int;
  };
};
```

I'd like to be able to form a typdef/using:

```cpp
template<typename T1,typename T2>
using type2 = A<T1>::B<T2>::type;
//... and use like
type2<int,char> foo;
```

GCC complains that I need `typename A<T1>::B<T2>::type` instead, and afterwards complains that it expects ";" before "<" after B (i.e. `typename A<T1>::B`)

is there no way to use "using" with nested templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch from

```
using type2 = A<T1>::B<T2>::type;
```

to

```
using type2 = typename A<T1>::template B<T2>::type;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `B` is a templated class and `type` is enclosed in a templated class, hence use the following

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T1>
struct A {
    template<typename T2>
    struct B {
        using type = int;
    };
};

template<typename T1,typename T2>
using type2 = typename A<T1>::template B<T2>::type;

int main()
{
    type2<int,char> foo =2;
    std::cout << foo;

}
```